# Enabling developer mode(for bash) on Windows 10 (10586.1007) doesn't prompt for reboot, nor installs required files

Tags: windows-10, bash

I've had the developer mode running on other machines to use the linux subsystems.

When enabling the developer mode, I should get prompted for a reboot to do the req. installs. Now however, when I chose developer mode on this clean install, I get no such prompt.

As a result, I believe i'm missing the developer mode updates. How can I acquire these?

Comment: Did you get any error in developer mode in settings app? BTW, from build 16215 windows 10 no longer requires developer mode [article](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2017/06/08/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-16215-pc-build-15222-mobile/).

Comment: No erros. I'm on build 10586, so that's a lot lower. I read that the Linux subsystems were available from 1400 and higher. Now that I'm reading up on it, it might have been 14000 instead. I'm trying to update my build now

Comment: Ok then just enable developer mode, enable WSL in Windows feature as usual. Then restart PC. Try to install Ubuntu and see what happens?

Comment: We need more information.  Are you using anything other than Home or Professional?